# Grid is not listening to cell's 'min-width: min-content'

Tags: css, resize, css-grid

I have the next grid layout:

```
| options | header    header  |
| nav     | resizer | content |
```

`resizer` is a narrow line for `nav`<->`content` horizontal resizing. I want to set `min-width: min-content` to `nav` and then resize the *grid cells* `nav` and `content`, but when I try to make `nav` smaller than its `min-content` width, the `nav` *block* stops resizing, but the `nav` *cell* becomes smaller, and the `nav` block's width is bigger than the `nav` cell's width as a result.

When I set `min-width: Npx` for `nav`, all is fine and the *grid cell* `nav` has always the same width as the *block* `nav`.

The question is, how can I set `nav`'s minimal width to `min-content` and have the grid listening to the actual `nav` width as he does with `Npx` values.

[Jsfiddle with the example.](https://jsfiddle.net/c2ourfa4/4/)

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/c2ourfa4/5/

Comment: @Michael_B, is it supposed to be like that? http://i.yapx.ru/C3J6z.jpg

Comment: I set the `min-width` to 0 on `nav` and `#options`. So the resizer can collapse the column to 0. You can change the setting if you wish.

Comment: @Michael_B, try to set `min-width` for `nav` and `#options` to, for example, `200px` and then resize `nav` to the point it becomes *smaller* then its *cell*. The point is I need the grid sizes to match the blocks' actual sizes. Here is an example with `200px` set, just resize `nav`: https://jsfiddle.net/c2ourfa4/6/

Comment: Besides, I need something like `min-content` for `nav` minimal width, I would use values in pixels if that was not the case.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Also, please add your demo code to the question itself. Otherwise, your question is less useful to others and may be closed for violating [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).